# How do i auto-refresh my log rather then refreshing it manually

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I currently have a log box which shows the log from my backend. I have a button to refresh the log and the latest set of logs shows up. How do I set it to a auto-refresh log?

I have the code below for the button and switchbox

```html
<div class="form-group row m-b-10">
  <label class="col-form-label">Auto-Refresh:</label>
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="switcher switcher-success">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" name="switcher_checkbox_2" id="switcher_checkbox_2" checked="true" value="1" v-on:change="toggle">
      <label for="switcher_checkbox_2"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="switcher switcher-success">
      <button v-if="!checked" @click="logNode(namespace)" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Refresh</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the function for the refresh button is below. How do I call a function for the log to load on auto refresh when the switchbox is on?

```js
logNode(namespace) {
  console.log(namespace)
  this.hidemodal = true;
  this.logShow = true;
  var requestobj = {
    Namespace: namespace,
  };
  var apiobj = {
    tablename: "bnm",
    Id: VueCookies.get("activeNetwork_Id"),
    method: "post"
  };
  var obj = {
    apiobj: apiobj,
    mainobj: requestobj
  };
  this.$store
    .dispatch("logsAPI", obj)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log("test result");
      if (response.data || response.status == 200) {
        this.logString = response.data.Logstr;
        this.$notify({
          group: "querynotify",
          title: "Success",
          type: "success",
          position: "top-right",
          text: "Sucessfully Created Logs " + ":\n" + response.data.Username
        });
      } else {
        this.$notify({
          group: "querynotify",
          title: "Error",
          type: "warn",
          position: "top-right",
          text: "Error Creating Logs " + ":\n" + response.data.Username
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.$notify({
        group: "querynotify",
        title: "Error",
        type: "error",
        position: "top-right",
        text: "Error View this node Log" +
          ":\n" +
          error.data.err +
          ":\n" +
          error.data.details
      });
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check box is checked, you can use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and when your checkbox is unchecked [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

Please check below working snippet.

***Note** in this snippet, I have just used simple log for demo purpose. In that demo you can put your logic.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checked: false,
    autoRef:null
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      if(this.checked){
        this.autoRef = setInterval(() => {
          this.logNode('Auto refresh called');
        }, 3000);
      }else{
        clearInterval(this.autoRef);
      }
    },
    logNode(msg) {
      console.log(msg)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.btn-success {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.2/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.2.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="form-group row m-b-10">
  <label class="col-form-label">Auto-Refresh:</label>
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="switcher switcher-success">
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" name="switcher_checkbox_2" id="switcher_checkbox_2" checked="true" value="1" v-on:change="toggle">
      <label for="switcher_checkbox_2"></label>
    </div>
    <div v-if="!checked" class="switcher switcher-success">
      <button ref="myButton" @click="logNode('on button click')" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Refresh</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It works! But, If i do not turn off the switch, the auto refresh continues while navigating to other pages too.. Is there any option to turn off that?

Comment: @user6345655 it will, but in this case you can make some certain condition if reached that limit then it will automatically turnoff that.